# Como puedo hacer para pasar de string a objetos DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un archivo txt con un listado de referencias a elementos del DOM ('div'), quiero pasarlos a un array para acceder a ellos, pero al pasarlos quedan como un string y no como una coleccion de objetos.

Este es el contenido de mi archivo txt; del que estoy intentando sacar las referencias al dom.

```
"[document.querySelector('.c0 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c0 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c1 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c1 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c2 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c2 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c3 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c3 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c4 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c4 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c5 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c5 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c6 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c6 .f11')],
[document.querySelector('.c7 .f0'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f1'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f2'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f3'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f4'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f5'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f6'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f7'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f8'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f9'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f10'),
document.querySelector('.c7 .f11')]"
```

Aqui el archivo html con el que estoy trabajando; lo que quiero hacer es acceder a los div desde el script sin colocar todas las referencias a cada div en el codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Lectura Escritura De Archivos</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">

*{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
}

#tablaDatos{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.columna {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.celda {
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: solid 0.05rem #999;
}

.celda  div:first-child {
  color: blue;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.celda div:last-child {
  color: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  html{
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
      font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  body{
      margin: 1rem auto;
      background-color: #F6F6F6;
      color: #333;
  }

}</style>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src='script.js'></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="tablaDatos">
        <div class="columna c0">
          <div class="celda f0">
            <div>HORA</div>
            <div>DIA</div>
          </div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c1">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c2">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c3">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c4">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c5">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c6">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columna c7">
          <div class="celda f0"></div>
          <div class="celda f1"></div>
          <div class="celda f2"></div>
          <div class="celda f3"></div>
          <div class="celda f4"></div>
          <div class="celda f5"></div>
          <div class="celda f6"></div>
          <div class="celda f7"></div>
          <div class="celda f8"></div>
          <div class="celda f9"></div>
          <div class="celda f10"></div>
          <div class="celda f11"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

El codigo del script que estoy usando, primero obtengo los datos del archivo de texto; luego los voy agregando a un arreglo; el problema es que los datos que se pasan al arreglo quedan como string y no como referencias al DOM.

```
//===================================================================================================

window.addEventListener('load', domIniciado);

function domIniciado(){
  
  const objetosDom =[];
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  let archivoTexto = "";
  let pasaTexto = [];
  
  xhr.open('GET', 'ArrayObjetos.txt', true);
  xhr.send();
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
      
      archivoTexto = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(archivoTexto);
      
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      let k = 0;
      let elementoDom = "";
      
      for(i = 0; i <= archivoTexto.length; i++){
        //console.log (i);
        //console.log(archivoTexto.charAt(k));
        
        if(archivoTexto.charAt(i) === '['){
          
          k = i + 1;
          elementoDom = "";
          
          while(archivoTexto.charAt(k) !== ']'){
            elementoDom += archivoTexto.charAt(k);
            k++;
          }
          
          JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( elementoDom ) );
          
          objetosDom[j] = [elementoDom];
          j++;
        }
      }
      console.log(objetosDom);
    }
  }
}
```

Quiero importar las referencias desde un txt a un arreglo usando javascript.

No se como hacerlo.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar estoy iniciando en esto de la programacion.

Comment: con que fin creas ese archivo txt? estas intentando estilizar los div's del DOM?

Comment: Estoy empezando con javascript; como la lista de las referencias es muy larga la estoy sacando fuera en un archivo y que el codigo lea desde ese archivo las referencia.

Comment: lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es que estas tratando de estilizar los div's ? estoy equivocado ?

Comment: Hola @yoenbolivia, si lo quieres tener como una colección de objetos deberías considerar utilizar `document.querySelectorAll( ".columna .celda" )` y allí tendrás todos los elementos **HTML**. Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es poder hacer clic sobre uno de los elementos para realizar una acción, como seleccionar algo, considere utilizar **[eventos delegados (versión en inglés)](https://ed.team/blog/como-usar-la-delegacion-de-eventos-en-javascript)**. Al menos, aquí se explica de forma sencilla.

Comment: *Enzo*, lo que quiero es sacar del codigo la lista de las referencias al DOM, esta lista es pequeña en comparacion con la.lista completa, porque quiero hacer con array es porque necesitp acceder a cada elemento en algun momento determinado y debo precisar la referencia a cada elemento 'div'

Comment: David; tengo una base de datos en indexeddb y cuando el usuario seleccione un rango de fechas los valores correspondientes deben escribirse en la celda correspondiente, perdonen mi inexperiencia pero realmente lo que quiero hacer es sacar el listado de las referencia fuera del codigo. Tambien puedo usar un ciclo for anidado para tener la referencia en fila y columna (Array [f][c]); pero, no lo he logrado por eso intente sacarlos a un txt.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el vinculo a los eventos delegados, lo estoy estudiando, a ver como lo implemento en mi proyecto.

Comment: Enzo, David asi lo resolvi por ahora: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/418200/207564

Answer (score 0):

Bien amigos; cuando pase las referencias Dom al archivo txt, mi intencion era no escribir el listado directamente en el codigo; ya no segui intrntando con el archivo txt, sino que utilice FOR anidado y el metodo SPLICE parainsertar un arreglo dentro de otro sin duplicar los elementos.

Les dejo el script para que me den su opinion de otras formas para mejorar este codigo.

```
window.addEventListener('load', domIniciado);

function domIniciado(){
  
  const tablaCelda = [];
  const tablaFilas = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i <= 7; i++){
    for(let j=0; j <= 11; j++){
      tablaFilas.push(document.querySelector('.c'+i+' .f'+j));
    }
    tablaCelda.push(tablaFilas.slice());
    tablaFilas.splice(0);
  }
  
  console.log(tablaCelda);
  
  for(let c=0; c <= 7; c++){
    for(let f=0; f<=11; f++){
      tablaCelda[c][f].innerHTML = "C"+c+",F"+f;
    }
  }
}
```